# getting 'permission denied' error while executing command in putty

Tags: laravel-4, ssh, putty

I installed composer in server. Now i want to make it global to use it in laravel 4.
So for that i used this command

```
 mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

But getting this error,

`mv: cannot create regular file '/usr/local/bin/composer': Permission denied`.

Even `sudo` not working

Is there any solution for this? or have to contact service provider?

Comment: Your question is [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: getting this error `-bash: sudo: command not found` @PatNowak

Comment: why there is down vote for question?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl please check this  `software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development`

Comment: Exactly, **"that is unique to software development"**. Your problem nowhere unique to the software development. It's a simple file permissions problem.

Comment: composer is ` software tools commonly used by programmers`

Answer (score 0):

use the command with sudo:

```
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

However you need to be in sudoers group. If it still not working, contact yours server administrator. If you are administrator google for: add user to sudoers.